# How to plot bar chart wth continuous coloring

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to plot a bar chart with continous coloring, similar to `scale_fill_brewer()` but more continously?

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would comment on this, but not enough rep yet...

Your problem with the Diamonds data set is that the data is discrete, meaning each value / observation belonging to it is distinct and separate. In order to do a continuous fill you need continuous data (values / observations belonging to it may take on any value within a finite or infinite interval).

When you have a continuous data set you can use the following ggplot2 command: [scale_colour_gradient](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_gradient.html).

**EDIT**

You can try this: `ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=..count..)) + geom_bar()`, but you loose the *Cut* information:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Color Brewer has sequential color schemes built in - check [colorbrewer2.org](http://colorbrewer2.org).  For instance,

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="PuBu")
```

yields

[image]

### Update:

Per OP's comment below, it appears that OP wants to map `alpha` to the factor levels of `cut`, with `alpha` decreasing as factor levels increase (i.e., `alpha` for 'Fair' should be higher than `alpha` for `Ideal`). We can manually assign  `alpha` using `scale_alpha_manual`, but a simpler solution is to use `scale_alpha_discrete` with the `levels` argument defined 'in reverse':

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, alpha=cut)) + geom_bar(fill="darkblue") +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(1, 0.2)) #Note that range is ordered 'backwards'
```

Of course you can adjust the color using the `fill` argument to `geom_bar` (`darkblue` comes out looking fairly purple).

[image]

Comment: I know but it should look closer to `y<-hist(rnorm(1000),breaks=30)$count
df<-data.frame(x=1:length(y),y=y,key="A")
df2<-data.frame(x=1:length(y),y=y*0.4,key="B")
df<-rbind(df,df2)
p<-ggplot(df,aes(x=x))
p<-p + geom_bar(subset=.(key =="A"),aes(y = y),stat="identity",fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
p<-p + geom_bar(subset=.(key =="B"),aes(y = y),stat="identity",fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
p`

Comment: In what sense should it look closer - in terms of the actual colors that are used? In terms of alpha? I think you are looking for something more specific than you have specified in your question, but I can't quite tell what.

Comment: Not in terms of a specific color. Rather in terms of the alpha, it should look that a container get filled with water.